# How do I install python on alpine linux?

Tags: python, linux, alpine-linux

How do I install python3 and python3-pip on an alpine based image (without using a python image)?

```
 $ apk add --update python3.8 python3-pip
 ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
   python3-pip (missing):
     required by: world[python3-pip]
   python3.8 (missing):
     required by: world[python3.8]
```

Comment: This might help https://github.com/jfloff/alpine-python

Comment: OP specifically asks how to accomplish the task without using a python image.

Comment: You're obviously interested in installing python3.8, not just any version of python3. However, none of the answers address this. Has anyone figured out how to install a specific minor version of python3?

Comment: @TobiasFeil check out my answer, I think this is a possible alternative.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

This is what I use in a Dockerfile for an alpine image:

```
# Install python/pip
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Comment: I'm getting:
`WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: No such file or directory
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  python3 (missing):
    required by: world[python3]`

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware that `python3 -m ensurepip` exists.

Comment: @Zac This error may occur if you have no `community` repository enabled in your `/etc/apk/repositories`. Check this file, uncomment or add `community` repository and retry.

Comment: `ensurepip` is pretty cool, for those interested here is more info on it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html

Comment: In the Alpine 3.19 image, running *python3 -m ensurepip* gives a long error message starting with "This environment is externally managed".  Ih that case, use Linus H.'s answer: *apk add --no-cache py3-pip*.

Answer (score 122):

Take a look at the alpine package repo: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages
So what you are looking for are the `python3` and `py3-pip` packages.

A suitable command to use inside a dockerfile/etc. would be:

```
apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip
```

[Explanation of the `--no-cache` flag](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md#disabling-cache)

Note however, that you need to [add the community repository](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_newbie_apk_packages#enable_repository_packages) since `py3-pip` is [not present](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=py3-pip) on `main`.

Comment: what's the equivalent of `python-dev` package for 3?

Comment: @chovy it's `python3-dev` according to: [Alpine Package search: python3-dev*](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=python3-dev*)

Comment: This is the correct way since `3.12` https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=pip3&path=&name=&branch=v3.12

Comment: If you come across this error `importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: pip` while trying to run e.g. `pip3 install` and you are using `alpine:3.13` docker image, try upgrading to `alpine:3.14`.

Comment: It seems py3-pip already present on main: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=py3-pip

Comment: Sorry @johnlinp, but I can not reproduce your findings. When opening the link you have provided, it clearly states, that `py3-pip` is only available in the `community` repo.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I'm sorry.

Comment: Since Python now makes `python3 -m ensurepip` fail for system-installed Python, that makes `sudo apk add --no-cache py3-pip` the way forward.

Comment: That link to the community repository is broken, and py3-pip always gets an error says missing.

Answer (score 26):

instead of **python3-pip** install **py3-pip**

```
apk add --update python3 py3-pip
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: This doesn't work, at all, I get py3-pip missing.

Answer (score 22):

Additional option is to *build* python during image build:

```dockerfile
FROM alpine:latest

# you can specify python version during image build
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.9

# install build dependencies and needed tools
RUN apk add \
    wget \
    gcc \
    make \
    zlib-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    musl-dev

# download and extract python sources
RUN cd /opt \
    && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz \                                              
    && tar xzf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz

# build python and remove left-over sources
RUN cd /opt/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} \ 
    && ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install \
    && make install \
    && rm /opt/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz /opt/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} -rf
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               # rest of the image, python3 and pip3 commands will be available
```

This snippet downloads and builds python of specified version from sources (together with pip). It may be an overkill but sometimes it may come in handy.

Answer (score 17):

You can try this command:

```
apk add python3
```

Answer (score 12):

You may use the python official image which offers alpine tags as well. You will probably get the most state-of-the-art python install:

e.g.:

`FROM python:3-alpine`

Comment: Presently, I tried your method as in `FROM python:3.9-alpine:edge`. But this throws invalid reference format. I require alpine edge because librdkafka 2.0.2 v is available only in alpine edge. Is there any other way to solve this error?

Comment: @potterson11 I guess the tag you used (python:3.9-alpine:edge) does not exists. I have not seen any available edge tags here: https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to install a specific minor version of Python3 (3.8), you can do this in Alpine by using semver like this which will install a version of `python3>=3.8.0 <3.9.0-0`:

```
apk add python3=~3.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to install python in an air gap network so I couldn't run `apk add`. Here's how I got required packages inside an online alpine container:

```
apk fetch python3 py3-pip libbz2 libexpat libffi gdbm mpdecimal libpanelw readline \
    sqlite-libs py3-setuptools libgcc libstdc++ py3-packaging py3-parsing
```

And my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
COPY ./*.apk .

RUN apk add --allow-untrusted --no-network libgcc* libstdc++* gdbm* libbz2* \
    libexpat* libffi* libpanel* mpdecimal* \
    readline* sqlite* \
    python3-3.11.4-r0.apk py3-parsing* py3-packaging* py3-setuptools* py3-pip-23.1.2-r0.apk && \
    rm *.apk && \
    ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
```

And the dependency hell got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to install `pip` in Alpine Linux you might not get `py3-pip` to install via `apk`. After you install python: `apk add python3`, then you run `python -m ensurepip`. That's what worked for me.

Good luck!

Comment: This works. You can verify that pip was installed with `python -m pip --version`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many answers from different sources, eventually I copied the repository file and checked the naming convention by extracting the compressed file

```
wget https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
tar -xvf  APKINDEX.tar.gz
cat APKINDEX | grep python3
```

and the found the line.

```
D:python3 python3~3.11
```

and the following worked

```
apk --update --no-cache add python3~3.11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```