# Macbook m1 node js docker image build failed

Tags: node.js, docker, apple-m1

This is message:
[image]

What's wrong? I should wait for the production docker?

This is docker config:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: Seems like one of the dependencies require python to be inside the docker image

Answer (score 10):

Try running it with linux/amd64.

In your docker config change:

`FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage`

to

`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:lts-alpine as build-stage`

Answer (score 2):

You need python with `make` and `g++` to build your dependencies.

```
FROM node:14-alpine as frontbuild  
#RUN apk add --no-cache python2 make g++ WORKDIR /tmp

COPY ./front/package.json .

RUN apk add --update --no-cache python2 make gcc libsass g++

RUN npm install --no-optional  --only-production

COPY front /tmp

ARG VUE_APP_BASE_URL ENV VUE_APP_BASE_URL $VUE_APP_BASE_URL ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN npm run build
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution of Y H helps to add `--platform=linux/amd64` in the `FROM` statement.

But if you don't want to change your `Dockerfile`, you can also set `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM` before building the docker image:

export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64

Answer (score 1):

You need to install python as part of your build process. For more details how to install python check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554991/how-do-i-install-python-on-alpine-linux)

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Comment: same loop, check if the binary/library/package is missing, and if so add to the Dockerfile. If you ware not tracking the dependancies properly, you will need to repeat this cycle several times until you find all the things that you are missing.

Comment: I recently bought a MacBook m1, in Linux os docker file was ok and no problem.

Comment: M1 is ARM64, some libraries/packages are still not available for M1, but it's not the case with `node-gyp`, it's most probably a problem with installation of the C/C++ build environment.  Add `apk add alpine-sdk` to the Dockerfile and check agin.

Answer (score 1):

For me this only worked

Changing

```
FROM node:14-alpine
```

to

```
FROM node:14
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need python. And the already provided answers here will provide you with that and the minimalist might be looking for something like that.

Another option would be not to use the alpine version of node (which comes for good reasons with a minimized footprint). I've personally accepted the overhead of a bigger image in favor of saving time by not installing python. So my (potentially opinionated) solution would be to just replace

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
...
```

with

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts as build-stage
...
```