npm not found during Docker build
I am very much a noob with Docker, node, etc. but have spent several hours searching for solution and not found anything.  My Dockerfile is very simple:
# Added to fix building on ARM64 - causing error on AWS
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.7-alpine

# Set the working directory inside the Docker container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json for installing dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies defined in package.json
RUN npm install

etc....

In this directory I run
Docker build -t my-web-app .
and it proceeds for a bit and fails like this:
 > [4/6] RUN npm install:
0.130 /bin/sh: npm: not found

But from command line I can get npm and node to return their version, so they are available.  Their location is in the $PATH.  If I go to the npm file it links to npm-cli.js which reads:
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../lib/cli.js')(process)

I checked the path in the env and nothing wrong there.
If I run /bin/sh npm -v as a test I get a different error: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token'../lib/cli.js''`. That file exists in the location and looks reasonable.
This is a fresh install of node - v20.12.2 and npm - 10.5.0
I've installed and removed node first with brew, then with docker, then with nvm and finally with the MacOS ARM64 installer from nodejs.org.  I am using bash instead of zsh. I'm on M1 Macbook Pro.
Have reviewed most of the similar posts on here and they all seem much more complicated.  This seems to be a path issue of some sort but I'm not seeing it.
I monkeyed around with the second line of the npm-cli.js file - removing quotes, removing the (process) part, etc. on off chance it was something simple like that.

So there are two different contexts when talking about docker:

the "host" is essentially your computer (wherever docker is installed)
the "build" context is a separate context created when you run docker build ...

When you run docker build ..., docker creates a build context inside of which your Dockerfile is executed. You can think of this build context kind of like running a VM, and the python-alpine image is your base image. All of the docker commands in your Dockerfile are run inside the python-alpine image, not on your host (read that last sentence one more time).
So your host machine might have node, npm, MS Office, ...whatever installed... but the python-alpine image does not have any of this. "Alpine" is basically the smallest and lightest version of linux out there - so when you see an image like python-alpine, you are basically getting a very tiny linux image with nothing else but python installed. Similarly, node distributes node-alpine images which have nothing else but node installed.
So if you are wanting to run both node and python together, you will need to pick one to use as your "base" image, and then you can install the other on top of that.  I'm most familiar with starting with node, and then installing python:
FROM node:20-alpine

# Install python/pip
# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554991/how-do-i-install-python-on-alpine-linux
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools

If you want to start with your python-alpine image, then you should be able to search for "Install node on alpine" for easy commands for installing node.

Thanks - this is very helpful in terms of understanding how docker works.  I was handed this project - which was working for person working on a PC - and I could get it to work locally on my M1 Mac, but it was not deploying on AWS Lightsail.  One of my 'fixes' ended up breaking something else.  Your post helped me take a deep breath and see my mistake.
